# Find vtable without complete object locator

Tags: c++, vtables, virtual-functions

I am learning to reverse Visual C++ objects.

I usually find the vtable (or VMT of VFT, however you call it) of the object using a cross reference to its `CompleteObjectLocator` that I found in the disassembled binary before (using a cross reference to the object's `TypeDescriptor` or `ClassHierarchyDescriptor`). The pointer to `CompleteObjectLocator` is the -1st field of the vtable.

However, as some classes are probably abstract in my program, they do not have `CompleteObjectLocator`s. **How do I find their vtables?**

I know that the program writes the pointer to the vtable down to `this` in the object's constructor, however in my program the constructors are inlined in the child class constructors and there I do not see work with memory that could be the vtable of the parent.

For example:

- `ClassA` inherits from `ClassB` (probably abstract) that inherits from `ClassC` that inherits from `ClassD` (probably abstract). I found this information in the `BaseClassArray` of each of the classes.
- I am able to find vtable of `ClassA` and using a cross reference on it, I find its constructor
- In the constructor of `ClassA` I see the program work with vtable of `ClassC` and vtable of `ClassA` (constructors are inlined, pointer to vtable of `ClassC` is written to a location and three instructions later it is rewritten by the pointer to vtable of `ClassA`)
- I would expect to see some work with vtables of `ClassB` and `ClassD` in the constructor of `ClassA` as well. I would expect the pointer to vtable of `ClassB` to be written do the memory somewhere between the work with vtables of `ClassA` and `ClassC`, but there are only instructions that basically do nothing, only move some content from register to register.
- Or, if the constructor of `ClassA` wouldn't work with vtables of `ClassB` and `ClassD`, I would expect at least calling their constructors from there, which does not happen as well.

I know I could find a vtable dynamically, because it would be the first element of `this`, but I do not know where (if anywhere) `this` of `ClassB` and `ClassD` is used. Can I find their vtables and constructors statically?

Comment: Don't forget that vtables might not exist for all classes as MSVC can be told not to produce a vtable by declaring a class with __declspec(notable)

Comment: __declspec(novtable) that is

Comment: @IanCook I see, thank you very much for the comment. Is it possible that this is not the case and the vtables exist somewhere even though I do not see them used in the constructors of the derived classes?

Comment: Add some C++ code for example to understand clearly.